# Creating a join table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, database-management

Let's say I have two tables, A and B, each with unique ID columns A_id and B_id respectively. Then let's say I wake up one day and decide that the two tables have  a relationship. So, I create a table AB that contains A_id, B_id pairs. Then I go to write a SQL server script that inserts these pairs based on other data in the tables, say A_name and B_name. I'd expect the actual insertion to work something like this (though with more advanced WHERE clauses typed in by the user though a Powershell script or something):

```
INSERT INTO AB (A_id, B_id) 
VALUES 
((SELECT (A_id) FROM A WHERE A_name = 'bob'), 
 (SELECT (B_id) FROM B WHERE B_name = 'john'))
```

I'm not sure of the correct syntax for such an operation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want to use a [JOIN](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php) operation, and then `SELECT` from it's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting from two sub-selects, you should select from a join of the two tables, using whatever logic you are going to use:

```
INSERT INTO AB (A_id, B_id)
SELECT a.A_id, b.B_id
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
 ON A.SomeColumn=B.SomeColumn
```

Or, to replicate your example more precisely, it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO AB (A_id, B_id)
SELECT a.A_id, b.B_id
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
 ON A.A_name='bob'
 AND B.B_name='john'
```

Comment: There is no A.SomeColumn that equals B.SomeColumn. The logic there would probably be too advanced for a SQL script, or simply be specified by the user: "Hmmm... I think Bob and John should be related via the AB table..."

Comment: Didn't catch your addition until after the comment.